# swift enum pattern matching without if, guard or switch

Tags: swift

Is there a shorter way or a *oneliner* to write the following?

```
let string: String?
if case let .someCase(temp) = someEnum {
    string = temp
} else {
    string = nil
}
```

It would be nice to have something like:

```
case let .someCase(string) = someEnum
```

Does this not exists or do I simply not know it?

Comment: I think the `guard case` or `if case` are as short as you can get it

Comment: `if case` _is_ the short version. The long version, and the only way until `if case` came along, was a full-fledged `switch` statement.

Comment: You could always add a computed property to the enum if you want; see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/45849874/2976878

Comment: @Hamish: Looks like a duplicate to me.